# have issue with if else in stored procedure

Tags: mysql

I am using if else if in stored procedure 
But it producing error

> Error Code: 1064
>       You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'SELECT '0' responseCode,'Please enter age!!!'  responseMessage;
>           ELSEIF IFNUL' at line 35

I don't know where is the syntax error occur in my procedure

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE
    /*[DEFINER = { user | CURRENT_USER }]*/
    PROCEDURE `saathi`.`proc_test`(
    p_nameAlias VARCHAR(50),
    p_age VARCHAR(50),
    p_dob DATE,
    p_gender VARCHAR(50),
    p_email VARCHAR(50),
    p_occupation VARCHAR(50),
    p_educationLevel VARCHAR(50),
    p_userName VARCHAR(50),
    p_password VARCHAR(50),
    p_district INT(11),
    p_state INT(11),
    p_placeofOrigin VARCHAR(50),
    p_mobile VARCHAR(50),
    p_maritalStatus VARCHAR(50),
    p_behaviour VARCHAR(50),
    p_hydc VARCHAR(50)
    )
    /*LANGUAGE SQL
    | [NOT] DETERMINISTIC
    | { CONTAINS SQL | NO SQL | READS SQL DATA | MODIFIES SQL DATA }
    | SQL SECURITY { DEFINER | INVOKER }
    | COMMENT 'string'*/
    BEGIN
      IF IFNULL(P_nameAlias,'')=''
    THEN
    SELECT '0' responseCode, 'Please enter name!!!' responseMessage;

    ELSEIF IFNULL(p_dob,'')=''
    THEN
    SELECT '0' responseCode, 'Please enter dob!!!' responseMessage;
    ELSEIF IFNULL(p_age,'')=''
    SELECT '0' responseCode,'Please enter age!!!'  responseMessage;
    ELSEIF IFNULL(p_gender,'')=''
    THEN
    SELECT '0' responseCode,'Please enter gender!!!' responseMessage;

    ELSE 
    SELECT '200' responseCode,'Tested' responseMessage;

    END IF;
    END IF;
    END IF;
    END IF;

    END$$
```

it should compiled successfully

Comment: else if not elseif.

Comment: and ELSEIF IFNULL(p_age,'')='' missing a then

Answer (score 1):

There should be a space between **ELSE and IF**

Change `ELSEIF` to `ELSE IF`

and

Place a `THEN` after `IFNULL(p_age,'')=''`

Comment: sorry mam its occur because there is missing 'THEN' after ifnull(p_age,'')='' statement in "ELSEIF IFNULL(p_age,'')=''
    SELECT '0' responseCode,'Please enter age!!!'  responseMessage;" Thanks from my heart to provide your support